# Why is Vim's sort function case sensitive by default?

Tags: sorting, vim

In Vim, I select the following in a visual block:

```
Apple
Banana
APRICOT
```

And sort via `'<,'>sort`

Which results in

```
APRICOT
Apple
Banana
```

What I suppose to be the more common desire from a sort function, to do case insensitive alpha sorting, can be achieved by appending the `i` flag, `'<,'>sort i`, resulting in:

```
Apple
APRICOT
Banana
```

Am I missing a typical use case that makes sense to default this to case sensitive sorting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because sorting in C is case sensitive and that many vim commands and functions are just capsules around lib C?

BTW, UNIX `sort` filter is also case sensitive by default. I'd say most of us are expecting this behaviour. The contrary would be surprising actually.

PS: this is the kind of question you should ask on vim_dev mailing list.